# Manipulate dictionaries from values() output

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to use the ForeignKeys ids to search in other tables; to get the ids I am using:

```
infos = LOGIN.objects.filter(servicesName="example").values('user_id','passwd_id')
```

This returns:

```
<QuerySet [{'user_id': 2, 'passwd_id': 2}, {'user_id': 2, 'passwd_id': 3}]>
```

So here is my question: how can i get the value '3' from 'passwd_id'? Or even better, is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: For this query you can get it with `infos[1]['password_id']`, but that's probably not very useful, it depends on what you're doing and how you want to use the values. You may also iterate over `infos` and retrieve each id as you use it for whatever you want.

Comment: Iam already iterating but thanks for the advice, i tried to use "infos[1]['password_id']", but i get "list index out of range"

Comment: Well, it would work with the example query in the post, you must be trying with a different query that doesn't return at least two objects. If you're iterating, you can get `item['passwd_id']`, where `item` is the variable in the iteration. (By the way, in my first comment I used `password_id` instead of `passwd_id` that would be a `KeyError`).

Comment: Thats the weird part, the query in the post is the exactly output iam getting, so should work right ? When i use len(infos) i get 2, so i dont see where are my mistake

Comment: It should. You can edit the question and add the exact commands you're running and the output in the terminal, including from `print(infos)`, otherwise it's hard to guess why it's happening.

Comment: I figured out where my problem actually was, in the iteration loop thanks for your help